# Why is lactate dehydrogenase used to differentiate exudates from transudates?

Tags: diagnostics, enzyme

When differentiate transudates and exudates, the ration between effusion LDH and serum LDH is used:

> They are termed exudates if ... the pleural fluid to serum ratio of LDH (LDHR) is > 0.6, and transudates if ... the LDHR is < 0.6. (Joseph et al, PMID 11641512)

What is the mechanism that creates this difference between transudates and exudates?